# Passing hashes into create action in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to create a workout routine that gets created when a workout gets created by passing this in via ajax:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "workout"=>{"name"=>"cool workout", "desc"=>"super cool"}, "exerciseorder"=>["4", "2"], "repssets"=>{"0"=>["40", "4"], "1"=>["60", "6"]}}
```

Here is what my Create action looks like in my Workout Controller:

```
exercise_order = params[:exerciseorder]
repssets = params[:repssets]
@workout = Workout.new(workout_params)

if @workout.save
  WorkoutRoutine.create(
    [
      exercise_order.each_with_index.map { |x,i| 
        {
          :exercise_id => x,
          :position => i,
          :workout_id => @workout.id
        }
      },
      repssets.map { |x| x.last }.each { |y| 
        {
          :reps => y.first,
          :sets => y.last
        }
      }
    ]
  )
  render :nothing => true    
else
  render json: @workout.errors.full_messages, status: :unprocessable_entity
end
```

If I use an opening and closing '[]' within the WorkoutRoutine.create, it tells me:

```
ArgumentError: When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument.
```

And when I change them to '{}' it tells me:

```
syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting =>
```

I've tried a myriad of different combinations and work-arounds but can't seem to figure out why it won't correctly parse the data and save it to the database, any help is very appreciated.

**EDIT:**

When I remove the initial {} and [] from the WorkoutRoutine.create:

```
WorkoutRoutine.create(
    exercise_order.each_with_index.map { |x,i| 
      {
        :exercise_id => x,
        :position => i,
        :workout_id => 20
      }
    },
    repssets.map { |x| x.last }.each { |y| 
      {
        :reps => y.first,
        :sets => y.last
      }
    }
  )
```

I get this error message:

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 0..1)
```

**Edit2:**

This is the jQuery code that sents to the data field via ajax:

```
var getId = $(".exercise-list").sortable('toArray');
      ary = []

    $(getId).each(function () {
      id = $(this[0]).selector;

     var reps = $("#reps" + id).val();
     var sets = $("#sets" + id).val();

     ary.push([reps, sets])
    });

    var orderRepsSets = { exerciseorder: getId, repssets: ary }       
    var formData = $('#new_workout').serialize();
    var data = formData + '&' + $.param(orderRepsSets);

 $.ajax({
     url: $("#new_workout").attr('action'),
     method: 'POST',
     data: data,
     success: (function() {
     ....
  });
```

Comment: What does a `WorkoutRoutine` look like because you are passing a structure that looks like `[[{...},{...},{...}],[{...},{...},{...}]]` which is why it is complaining. Remember `map` returns an `Array` which you are nesting in an `Array`.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're asking, do you mean in the database? WorkoutRoutine(id: integer, exercise_id: integer, workout_id: integer, reps: integer, sets: integer, position: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime)

Comment: I assume that the `WorkoutRoutine` is and `ActiveRecord::Base` class, can you please attach it's schema and what is the connection with Workout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did I get it correctly that you want to create multiple WorkloadRoutine objects, one for each exercise with the corresponding repetitions, the position, etc. If yes, then in order to do that you will have to pass an array of hashes (one hash for each object) to the WorkoutRoutine.create() function. As engineersmnky correctly stated in his comment, the data structure you are currently passing is more like `[[{...},{...},{...}],[{...},{...},{...}]]`, but instead it should be just `[{...},{...},...]`. Do achieve that, something like this should do the trick:

```
WorkoutRoutine.create(
  exercise_order.map.with_index { |x,i| 
    {
      :exercise_id => x,
      :position => i,
      :workout_id => @workout.id,
      :reps => repssets[i.to_s].first,
      :sets => repssets[i.to_s].last
    }
  }
)
```

If you could change repssets to an array like exercise_order you could even remove the string cast for getting the reps and sets, which would simplify the whole think even more.

Comment: Right, but the problem is that with the workout routine, I'm also sending data for a Workout, so its' name and description, and a Workout has_many exercises through: :workout_routines, so in the database, I'm trying to send the workout name and description, then all of the correspondng exercises that apply to that workout with each exercise reps and sets that are stored in the WorkoutRoutine join table

Comment: Ok, but I still think, this should work. The workload data that is sent is saved in the newly created workload and thanks to the created workloadRoutines the workload should be connected with the exercise and the additional reps and sets information through the foreign_keys in the routine.

Comment: Yes!!! I had to modify it just a little bit after changing around my jQuery, so I was submitting "orderRepsSets = { orderrepssets: ary }" and my resulting hash was: Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "workout"=>{"name"=>"blahblah", "desc"=>"blhahaha"}, "orderrepssets"=>{"0"=>["1", "45", "10"], "1"=>["5", "55", "3"]}} so rather than repssets[i.to_s].first I did repssets[i.to_s][1] to get reps, etc. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

#### If it comes for errors they are quite self explanatory. But let's start from beginning..

I assume that `WorkoutRoutine` is an [`ActiveRecord::Base`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html) model. The `WorkoutRoutine.create` method gets 0 or 1 argument which should be a [Hash](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Hash.html) or a block.

In the first iteration you were passing an [Array](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Array.html) instead of [Hash](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Hash.html), so it looked like:

```
WorkoutRoutine.create([a, b]) # => ArgumentError: When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument.
```

On the second iteration you stripped away the square brackets, what gave you 2 arguments instead of one [Hash](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Hash.html):

```
WorkoutRoutine.create(a, b) # => ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 0..1)
```

If you read errors carefully you will start getting the idea what's happening.

#### About the workout routine itself

From what you specified I would assume that you want something like:

1. Workout has many Routines
2. Routine belongs to Workout and Exercise
3. Routine is composed of fields like

   - position/order,
   - number of repetitions,
   - number of sets

If my assumption is correct, then you want to use [nested_attributes](http://www.sitepoint.com/complex-rails-forms-with-nested-attributes/) and then have parameters and controller like

```
# given parameters as workout_params
{
  workout: {
    name: "workout name",
    desc: "workout description",
    routines_attributes: [
      { position: 1, exercise_id: 4, repetitions_number: 40, sets_number: 4 },
      { position: 2, exercise_id: 2, repetitions_number: 60, sets_number: 6 }
    ]
  }
}

# Controller
def create
  @workout = Workout.new workout_params

  if @workout.save
    redirect_to # ...
  else
    render :new
  end
end

private

def workout_params
  params.require(:workout).permit(:name, :desc, routines_attributes: [:position, :exercise_id, :repetitions_number, :sets_number])
end
```

It should be strait forward how to then create a view with `fields_for` and update models with proper associations

Comment: I should have mentioned that my data is being pulled via jQuery rather than a form, I'll post an Edit2 above with my jQuery code.

Comment: With `jquery-ujs` and `data-remote=true` on the form tag, you don't need to play around with js and as a bonus you have a proper parameters structure ;-)